# Page not opening after "Add to home screen"

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have a webapp running on my laptop and I can open and browse it on my iPad using my laptop's IP but when I create shortcut on home screen using "Add to home screen" and then tap on the icon, it keeps on loading the page and never finishes. I don't know if something taking that much time or there is an error. How to find out what's wrong? I cannot open debug console when it is running in full screen mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing anything today it started working :), look like some inconsistent implementation. BTW this time it took few minutes to load when I left iPad unattended and since earlier I was reloading it after 10-20s if the page is not visible so that means probably it takes more time to load if you make home icon.

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest you to change metatag for appcapable and set it to false so you can access the debug console and find out problem and solve it. After that you can restore the correct metatag and relaunch the webapp in fullscreen mode!

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="no">
```